# Feature Services & arcpy.ConsolidateMap_management & .replaceDataSource

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, feature-service

We have several in house published feature services, including some from our Esri Data Stores. When I use **arcpy.ConsolidateMap_management** on an mxd (10.1) the **Feature Services** are nicely consolidated into local file geodatabase, but the **layers are not re-sourced**.

When I use ArcCatalog to manually "set data source/s" in the mxd to the local file geodatabase, the paths are not present in the output mxd and no errors are produced.

Not stopping there. I then wrote some ArcPY to re-source the offending layers.The ArcPy works perfectly but the sources remain the same...

```
 if ISFS == 1: # Only proceed if it's an HTTP / Feature Service                     
            arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
            arcpy.AddMessage("     - FEATURE SERVICE TEST ---------------------" )
            arcpy.AddMessage("     - Layer Name: " + str(FSLyr))

        try:
            dataset_name = ("a"+str(FSFCNAME))
            arcpy.AddMessage("     - FS Data Source: " + str(LayerSource))
            arcpy.AddMessage("     - Consolidated fGDB: " + str(ConsolidatedFeatureServiceWorkspace))
            arcpy.AddMessage("     - Feature Class Name:" + dataset_name)
            FSLyr.replaceDataSource(ConsolidatedFeatureServiceWorkspace, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", dataset_name, False)
            arcpy.AddMessage("     - Replaced ")
            arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
            FeatureServiceMxd.save()
```

Results:
[image]

Before I investigate loading the file geodatabase feature class into the mxd and stealing the old cartography, does anyone know **why we are denied changing Feature Service Layer sources?**

Comment: If I open ArcMap and for each layer "set" the source. The layer remains set to the File Geodatabase Feature Class, as desired.

Comment: For ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 I have successfully added the feature class from the geodatabase and applied the feature service symbol. If this was a bug and fixed in 10.3 and 10.3.1 it will not enter the "add feature and symbolize loop.. "